# Understanding formula for generating random number in interval

Tags: javascript, math, random

I know that there are plenty of posts on this topic, but I can't find any that explain clearly enough for me why the formula works the way it does.

On [Mozilla's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to get a random number in (min, max), we have

```
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

But I don't understand how that is. If I take [4,10] for example,

```
r * (10 - 4) -> [0,6) // r to represent a random number in [0,1)
r * (10 - 4 + 1) -> [0, 7)
(r * (10 - 4 + 1)) + 4 -> [4, 11)
```

I don't know how that's supposed to give a random number in [4,10]. Could someone please explain?

Also, how do I get a random number in the open interval (a, b)?

Comment: Have you referred this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range

Comment: Since we are dealing with integers, `[4,10]` is the same as `[4, 11)`. To generate anteger in `(a,b)` simply note that this is the same as `[a+1, b-1]`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck But how do I generate a real number (not an integer) in (a, b)?

Comment: @RayonDabre Yes, I did. I read the chosen solution over and over. I understand it now by Klas's comment. However, the post doesn't say how to generate a real number in (a,b).

Comment: @AlanH Surely you mean floating point?